# How to return the list that contains a certain element in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I'm learning prolog but I have a problem with a code. I want to check if an element exists in a list of lists and if it exists I want to get the list that contains that element to manipulate the list. I made a clause to prove that the element is or not in the list of lists but I don't know how to get that list, please help me.

```
memberlist(X,[H|_]) :-
    member(X,H).
memberlist(X,[_|T2]) :-
  memberlist(X,T2).
```

I do this query:

```
memberlist("product1",[["product2", 100, "available"],["product3", 100, "sold out"],["product1", 200, "available"]]).
```

and I get: `true` but also I want to get the list that contains the string `"product1"` so the result that I'm looking for is: `["product1", 200, "available"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about introducing a third argument to store the matching list? e.g.:

```
memberlist(X,[H|_],H) :-
  member(X,H).
memberlist(X,[_|T2],Y) :-
  memberlist(X,T2,Y).
```

Example query:

```
memberlist("product1", [["product2", 100, "available"],["product3", 100, "sold out"],["product1", 200, "available"]], Result).
```

Produces the outcome:

```
Result = ["product1", 200, "available"]
```